# Delete and Undelete a Team Project in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I would like to delete a Team Project in TFS but when required i should be able to undelete the team project. However i only seem to be able to permanently delete a team project but i have similar projects in TFS that have been deleted but can be undeleted as well on demand as in the attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How do you delete a team project? How did you create the team project "TestBranchMerge" before? What's the difference between eam project "TestBranchMerge" and other team projects?

Comment: That screenshot is the source control tool. Are you talking about deleting source code from version control, or deleting a team project? They are not the same thing.

Comment: @Daniel deleting a team project. that screenshot is from visual studio source control and the red arrow is pointing at a team project which was deleted but clicking on the show deleted items icon (pointed in first red arrow), this team project shows up and gives me an option to undelete the team project.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT: I did not create or delete that particular team project. it was already there sitting deleted.

Comment: Can you see "TestBranchMerge" project in web portal?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT only if i undelete the team project otherwise no

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a team project permanently removes data associated with that project from the database. You cannot recover it later.

There are three ways to delete a team project, none of them can be recovered:

1. Delete from TFS Web Access:

   [image]
2. Delete from TFS administration console:

   [image]
3. Delete with [TFSDeleteProject](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd).

After deleting the team project, we are not able to see it any more.

Comment: yes, that's what i find it on google but in my company's source control, someone has managed to delete the team project and it still sits there as shown in the above screenshot. All the code inside the team project is lying deleted and it seems i can restore it perfectly fine.